# How to set NSLayoutConstraint constant in a collectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint, iboutlet

In my storyboard I have a set of constraints for the subview (called Thumbnail) in a cell

[image]

Then in my custom collectionView cell:

class PostViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
var portrait: Bool? {
    didSet {
        if portrait == true {
            print(self.bounds.height)
            thumbnailWidthConstraint.constant = self.bounds.width
            thumbnailHeightConstraint.constant = self.bounds.height/2
            thumbnailHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        } else {
            thumbnailWidthConstraint.constant = self.bounds.width/2
            thumbnailHeightConstraint.constant = self.bounds.height
        }
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailCenterYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
        portrait = false
    } else {
        portrait = true
    }
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

}

My goal is to change the height and width of the thumbnail like you see in the didSet method of the portrait variable. However, so far this seems unsuccessful. It prints a self.bounds.height of 536 and in the app it seems to be this height, not half the height as I am trying to set in the constraint. What step am I missing? Why isn't this working? Thanks!

Edit: In my view controller that contains the collectionView cells I have:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    postsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    postsCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

this collection view is called "postsCollectionView" in my view controller. Additionally, I have this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == timelineCollectionView {
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(2.5), height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)
    }
}
```

Thus when I rotate the phone and the collectionView becomes wider than it is tall, so does the cell inside. This hopefully sets the cell to re-layout subviews and alter the constraints as I have defined.

Comment: You are referencing self (a UIColelctionViewCell) as a reference for your dimensions. Where is the code that define's the cell's size. Does the size of this cell change based on orientation?

Comment: @Dare I added my view controller's sizeForItemAt for the collectionView which gives the height and width of each cell to be equal to the collectionView's height and width. When the device rotates to landscape mode, the collectionView becomes wider than it is tall and the portrait variable in my custom cell class is changed to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may miss re-layout after changing the constant

```
var portrait: Bool? {
    didSet {
        if portrait == true {
            print(self.bounds.height)
            thumbnailWidthConstraint.constant = self.bounds.width
            thumbnailHeightConstraint.constant = self.bounds.height/2
            thumbnailHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        } else {
            thumbnailWidthConstraint.constant = self.bounds.width/2
            thumbnailHeightConstraint.constant = self.bounds.height
        }

        self.layoutIfNeeded() // or  self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded() 
    }
}
```

---

You need also to respond to system orientation changes

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, 
               with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
  collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
  collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: thanks. I have included those changes in the question so you can see my implementation. Unfortunately the Thumbnail is still showing up full height.

Comment: can you comment this `thumbnailHeightConstraint.isActive = true` as if it's landscape control won't go to activate , and make it active where you set the constraints ?

Comment: you mean comment it out? yes I commented it out with // and the thumbnail still shows up as full height. Im not sure what you mean though - you're just saying that's not needed?

Comment: you made portarit/not according to **if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {** do you configure the cell with **sizeForItem** so it's size changes in landscape/portrait ??

Comment: ah yes I have it configured in sizeForItem so that its the same width and height as the collectionView itself. The collectionView itself becomes wider than it is tall if in landscape and the opposite if in portrait mode. I have edited the question to include this

Comment: omg Im dumb. I had the constant set to positive. So it was increasing in height, not decreasing. Now its fixed once I changed that with your suggestions. Though actually it seems it still works without layoutIfNeeded() in the collectionView and in the cell class